# Clear the cache of GPG : pub, uid and sub

Tags: gnupg

I am currently experimenting the key-pair using the command `gpg --gen-key` after I viewed the list using the command `gpg --list-keys` it is showing a bunch of

```
pub, ui and sub
```

combinations although I only need one of them. Is there a way to clear this list?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solve it anyway. Using the commands:

```
gpg --delete-secret-keys <keyid>
gpg --delete-keys <keyid>
```

Although you need to manually delete each key-pair.